# Android - SQLite Column does not exist from certain page

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I'm messing around with some SQLite databases for an Android app. I have a 'player' table with several players, and a one-to-many 'skill' table which has each player's skill points, like Shooting and Rebounding.

I have one activity in the app for actually filling out textboxes and inserting a player into the database. When the user hits the 'Add Player' button, a row is inserted into the 'player' table and a row is inserted into the 'skills' table which has a foreign key that references the 'player' table. After these inserts, I did a query to check if I could read the 'Shooting' value from the 'skills' table and put it in a Toast notification. That worked fine, and the code I used is here:

```
SQLiteDatabase db2 = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

String[] projection = { "shooting" };

String sortOrder = "shooting" + " DESC";

Cursor c = db2.query(
    "skills",       // The table to query
    projection,     // The columns to return
    null,           // The columns for the WHERE clause
    null,           // The values for the WHERE clause
    null,           // don't group the rows
    null,           // don't filter by row groups
    sortOrder       // The sort order
);

c.moveToFirst();

int shooting = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("shooting"));

Toast.makeText(this, "" + shooting, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

After I saw that this was working, I commented it out and put in an Intent to make the app switch to the 'Roster' activity after the player and skills are inserted. On the 'Roster' activity, I want to get each player's 'Shooting' skill. When I use the exact same code from above (which works from the other activity) I get an error which says:

> 06-16 15:59:42.602: E/AndroidRuntime(31537): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.silverray.messaround/com.silverray.messaround.Roster}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'shooting' does not exist

I can't figure out why it's saying the 'shooting' column doesn't exist when I know I included it in my SQL Create statement, and I was even able to read this exact same column with the same code from another activity.

Thanks for reading. Any ideas?

EDIT: This is the full code for the Roster activity:

```
public class Roster extends Activity {

    int teamID = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_roster);

        // CHECK ROSTER

        DatabaseContract dbContract = new DatabaseContract();
        DatabaseContract.DbHelper dbHelper = dbContract.new DbHelper(this);

        SQLiteDatabase dbCheck = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int ID = intent.getIntExtra("ID", 1);
        teamID = ID;

        String stringID = String.valueOf(ID);

        String[] projection = { "_id, playerFirstName, playerLastName, playerPosition" };
        String sortOrder = "playerFirstName" + " ASC";

        Cursor c = dbCheck.query(
            "player",
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            sortOrder
        );

        c.moveToFirst();

        int rowsAffected = c.getCount();

        if (rowsAffected < 1) {
            TextView rosterList = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtListRoster);
            rosterList.setText("Your team doesn't have any players!");
            c.close();
            dbCheck.close();
        } else {
            String players = "";

            for (int l = 0; l < rowsAffected; l++) {            
                String playerName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("playerFirstName"));
                String playerLastName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("playerLastName"));     
                String position = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("playerPosition"));
                int playerID = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));        
                String player_ID = String.valueOf(playerID);
                String pos = "";

                if (position.equals("Point Guard")) {
                    pos = "PG";
                } else if (position.equals("Shooting Guard")) {
                    pos = "SG";
                } else if (position.equals("Small Forward")) {
                    pos = "SF";
                } else if (position.equals("Power Forward")) {
                    pos = "PF";
                } else if (position.equals("Center")) {
                    pos = "C";
                }

                SQLiteDatabase db2 = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

                String[] projection2 = { "shooting" };

                String sortOrder2 = "shooting" + " DESC";

                Cursor c2 = db2.query(
                    "skills",
                    projection2,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    sortOrder2
                );

                c2.moveToFirst();

                //** Everything works until this line:

                int shooting = c2.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("shooting"));

                players += playerName + " " + playerLastName + " (" + pos + ") Shooting: ";

                if (l != (rowsAffected - 1)) {
                    players += "\n";
                }

                TextView rosterList = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtListRoster);
                rosterList.setText(players);

                if (l != (rowsAffected - 1)) {
                    c.moveToNext();
                }

                c2.close();
            }

            c.close();
            dbCheck.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.roster, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void addPlayer(View view) {

        Intent goToAddPlayer = new Intent(this, AddPlayer.class);
        goToAddPlayer.putExtra("ID", teamID);
        this.startActivity(goToAddPlayer);
        this.finish();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: post full code for Roster activity

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I just added in the code for the Roster activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int shooting = c2.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("shooting"));
```

should be

```
int shooting = c2.getInt(c2.getColumnIndexOrThrow("shooting"));
```

You are now working on 2nd query but trying to get column index from 1st.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that! I was looking right at it for hours hahaha. It works now. Thank you very much!